# HP Neverstop Laser MFP 1202nw does not Print PDF on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: printing, network-printer, hp, ubuntu-22.04

I recently purchased an `HP Neverstop Laser MFP 1202nw` which I successfully installed as wifi printer on my Ubuntu 22.04 System. It print smoothly when printing simple textfiles from gedit or pluma.

However, when I try to print a PDF, it simply refuses printing. The print job does not get stuck in the print queue, the printer even makes a noise indicating it must have received data. However, it does not print and even does not provide an error log.

What can I do?

---

Ubuntu provides me this information. Maybe this may help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The *HP Neverstop Laser MFP 1202nw* may be newer than the drivers in Ubuntu 22.04. Printing text is handled by a generic routine, but graphics in PDF files need a graphics printer driver.

Two suggestions:

- Update the [CUPS printer packages](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-cups). Perhaps there are newer versions that implement HP Neverstop compatibility.
- It's stated that the [HP Linux Imaging and Printing Driver [HPLIP] Now Supports Linux Mint 19.3](https://9to5linux.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing-driver-now-supports-linux-mint-19-3). Since Mint and Ubuntu have a common heritage, this likely would work in Ubuntu, as well. You can [install HPLIP](https://sites.google.com/site/tipsandtricksforubuntu/printer-info/hplip-driver) in Terminal, either by downloading the packages, or by adding *hplip-isv/ppa* as a trusted PPA as follows:

  `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hplip-isv/ppa`

  `sudo apt update`

  `sudo apt install hplip`

*N.B.:* Check carefully before you add any software PPA; I have not tried this source, myself.

Please let us know if either suggestion works for you, to help others with that issue.